# An exercise related to the domain of the fu....

Tags: functional-analysis

I have an exercise that I just want to be verified. Thank you in advance!
[image]

Please comment if it's something wrong:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analysis is fine up to the point where you reach the inequality $x^2-(1+a)x+a\le 0$. Solving the equality is fine, but your expressions are needlessly complicated, and could have been simplified. For note that we can rewrite the inequality as $(x-1)(x-a)\le 0$.

So the correct interval is $[a,1]$ or $[1,a]$, depending on whether $a\le 1$ or $a\gt 1$.

We want the interval to contain exactly $3$ positive integers. These must be $1$, $2$, and $3$. So the real $a$ that qualify are the $a$ such that $3\le a\lt 4$.

Comment: But why does not a equal only -1 and 3?

Comment: We have the intervals [a,1] and we have to find such an "a" that the cardinal of the interval with intersection with N is 3, so the only value of a can be -1, and the same for the second interval. May be I am wrong but I really want to find out

Comment: There is no way that the interval $[a,1]$ can contain $3$ elements of $\mathbb{N}$ (the natural numbers). For, depending on your definition of natural number, these are $1,2,3,4,\dots$ or $0,1,2,\dots$. For your other query, note that the questions asks for all **reals** such that the (maximal) domain of our function contains exactly $3$ natural numbers. So for example $a=\pi$ works.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations, you really helped me!!!